# C++/SDL Best method of infinite scrolling?

Tags: c++, scroll, sdl, infinite

I'm making a 2D snowboarding game, and I want the player to be able to ride infinitely, until they crash 3 times. I already have the terrain spawning in, but I don't know the best way to scroll.

Right now there is no scrolling, and once the player gets to the bottom of the screen, he pops back up to the top and new random terrain spawns.

Would it be better to have the background, including all the obstacles, scrolling from the bottom to the top of the screen, and the player essentially staying in the same location? Or should the player be scrolling downwards forever, as chunks of new terrain generate?

Answer (score 0):

The best is what you want your game to be like.

I would go for a continuously scrolling environment where the player might be able to move slightly forward backward (While scrolling at constant rate).

```
000000
0....0
0----0
0----0
0....0
000000
```

where the 0's are the edge of the screen the -'s are movable space and .'s are not movable space (Going up should be slow enough that with the scrolling screen that the player isn't moving uphill)

You will need to free objects that go out of the screen otherwise you are going to run into memory problems as the game progresses.

As for what should be scrolling. It really doesn't matter. If the ground moves and the player is stationary or the player and the camera moves across the stationary background: The user always sees a guy snowboarding down the hill. It's the illusion that it creates that counts.

In this case I would recommend a stationary player since you might run into trouble if the game goes on for a very long time and you start getting to the edges of what type you stored your position in. (Unless of course you used a wrapped coordinate system)